# Need to calculate record Age and record Total Age field with the use of enhanced SLA in Microsoft dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a requirement to calculate a record and record total age with the use of enhanced SLA. Is it possible?

Age : A record has a StartDate field and the value of StartDate is 1st March 2016 and there is another field named as EndDate and the value of EndDate is 31st March 2016, and the service getting hold for 3 days in this period, so the Age will be : 31 - 3 = 28

Total Age : Same as per above example but the difference is we does not need to include the hold days, So the Total Age will be : 31.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try [Calculated Fields](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn832103.aspx "Calculated Fields") ?

Comment: It seems very difficult to use calculated fields, because I need to exclude the hold time for Age field.

Answer (score 0):

I found this interesting blog post by Aileen Gusni here

> [Intercept Column/Field Value in CRM View using RetrieveMultiple Plugin C#](http://missdynamicscrm.blogspot.com.au/2016/03/intercept-columnfield-value-in-crm-view-retrievemultipleplugin.html)

Basically she creates a new field (in the example below it is `pa_age`), but she doesn't add it to the form or anything

Instead she catches the `Retrieve` and `RetrieveMultiple` messages in a Plugin and calculates this field as required.

I've pasted her code below

**Note** *this is not my code, it was written by Aileen*

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
   #region must to have

   IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

   IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));

   // Create service with context of current user
   IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

   //create tracing service
   ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

   #endregion

   //this is to modify the Age column

   if (context.OutputParameters.Contains("BusinessEntityCollection"))
   {
       var retrievedResult = (EntityCollection)context.OutputParameters["BusinessEntityCollection"];
       foreach (Entity entity in retrievedResult.Entities)
       {                 
           if (entity.Contains("birthdate"))
           {
               var birthday = entity.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("birthdate");
               int age = CalculateAgeYear(birthday);
               //modify the Age field
               entity.Attributes["pa_age"] = age;
            }
       }
   }
}
```

There are a few things to consider with this approach:

- The `pa_age` field's value never gets set. It is added to the entity only so that it can be included in the view
- this means that the `pa_age` field can't be included on the form or in reports because it will always be *null*
- you can't use the `pa_age` field in advanced finds (filter), but of course you can add it to the advanced find results. The reason for this is the same as before: the value isn't actually saved in the database

Her blog post has much more information and screenshots of how it all works. I haven't tried this approach but it might be useful for you